# New windows universal app with SQLite 3.8.7.4 doesn't work

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I created a windows universal app (windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1 winrt) working with SQLite 3.8.7.4.

But with SQLite, nothing works ! (The type or namespace name 'SQLite' could not be found)

[image]

**YES I have included SQLite in my references :**

[image]

**YES I tried to clean my project and to build it again,**

But I have no result. Does anyone have any idea?

I tried to update SQLite to 3.8.7.4 version on an existing app and it works, so, i continue to search why.

P.S : I'm using .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the difference between my 2 projects :

- In my existing app, there are 2 files : SQlite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs

But these files are not created on the 2nd project, that's why i can't find SQlite reference on my class.
These files are included by installing "sqlite-net" package from nugget.

Answer (score 0):

In universal app if you add this 2 files : SQlite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs in the "Shared project" then you will automatically get the reference of SQlite libraries in both project..
Refer the following link and follow the steps mention it'll help you 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826602/Using-SQLite-as-local-database-with-Universal-Apps

Answer (score 0):

SQlite.cs and
SQLiteAsync.cs.
These two files are also missing from my project and when I try to install SQLite-net visual studio give me error that it is already installed. I spend a lot of time on finding why it is not adding these files to my project. If you are also suffering from same problem just uninstall it then reinstall it will start working. 
:)